# Which weapons can take out guards in riot suits with helmets in one shot?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

The current FOB event mission, Bound Dragons (now coming around for the second time, and presumably recurring again in the future) features guards who all wear riot suits with full helmets. As in single-player, There's no way to take them out with a tranquilizer weapon, not even through the small gap between their helmet faceplate and chest protection. It seems like most rifles can't shoot off their helmets, and most shotguns won't even knock them down. (I haven't developed any of the high-grade online-only weapons, but I have the highest offline grades.) This is a big step up from the typical FOB guards in Battle Dress, who can fairly easily be taken out with headshots from lethal or tranquilizer weapons.

I mostly used CQC on riot suit guards during single-player, and now I'm struggling to find what else I can use to take them out. I know they're not protected from sleep grenades. The Brennan or Serval can kill them with a headshot, through their helmet. The rocket arm can stun them (I don't know if the blast arm can kill them). And Snake's running punch will knock them out and knock off their helmet. Since I'm trying to go non-lethal when possible, I've been mostly just using the rocket arm when playing this event, but that leaves me stuck with the Serval if I'm spotted or don't have time to fire the rocket arm.

Can any other weapons take out riot suit guards with one hit, or knock off their helmet to leave them vulnerable? Non-lethal and silent is preferable (e.g. if a high-grade shotgun can stun them) but lethal is acceptable.

Comment: By "take out guards in riot suits with helmets in one shot" do you mean only non-lethally? From the body of your question, it sounds like that's what you want, if possible. Or is lethal okay as well?

Comment: @DangerZone Both are fine - I just want to know what the tactical options are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The S-1000 Stun shotgun will knock out the riot suited guards in two hits, but it's really your best option. It's silenced for a good 20-25 shots or so, and you don't need to aim all that much, so it works great in third person. The range is also pretty decent. It's the weapon of choice for most non-lethal base infils. Just make sure you keep it constantly reloaded.

Answer (score 5):

I usually use sleep grenades to disable them. Sleeping grenades will do the job in one shot. You can attach them as underbarrel to both your Assault rifle and Sniping rifle which gives you a lot of grenades to work with. This is a non-lethal approch, but not a silent one, so guards will react when you shoot them. Also sleeping mines work very well.

Comment: How you attach Sleeping grenades to Assault Riffle? My attach grenades are lethal.

Comment: Develop the single shot grenade launcher that has sleep grenades and the option "underbarrel". Then in weapon customization you can attach that grenade launcher to your rifle (only if it allows underbarrel attachments of course). You will need to recruit the master weapons smith to enable weapon customization.